# create lines from points table

Tags: postgis, postgresql, st-makeline

I have a point table I have sorted by mmsi (it is the identifier) and by datetime columns.

```
  mmsi numeric,
  x1 double precision,
  y1 double precision,
  datetime timestamp without time zone,
  geom geometry(Point,3035)
  linetime2 (interval)
```

For each mmsi I would like to create a set of segments every 2 consecutive rows/points, skipping segments which have more then 6 hours of difference between the starting and the ending point AND more then 30 kilometers of distance between the starting and the ending points. the data are as follow:

[image]

Concerning the maximum distance between two consectutive points of the same mmsi I could calculate the line length in a second step and then delete lines longer than 30 km.

Concerning the maximun time interval I have calculted the time difference (column linetime2) between two consecutive points/rows using a lag function:

```
select mmsi, 
       datetime,
       datetime - lag(datetime) over (order by mmsi, datetime) as linetime
from test_st_12_v1;

with cte as (select mmsi, x1, y1, datetime, datetime - lag(datetime) over (partition by mmsi order by mmsi, datetime) as linetime
from test_st_12_v1)
update test_st_12_v1 lt
set linetime2 = ct.linetime
from cte ct
where lt.mmsi = ct.mmsi
and lt.datetime= ct.datetime;
```

Now, how can I create lines every two consecutive points with the same id (mmsi) skipping segments with a linetime2 > 6 hours? E.g. in the example I dont' want a segnemt between the points 9 and 10, 15 and 16, 83 and 84, and of course between 84 and 85 because I have another id number (mmsi).
Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `lag()` to find the next point, construct a line and compute its length

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT mmsi, x1, y1, datetime, 
        datetime - lag(datetime) OVER (PARTITION BY mmsi ORDER BY mmsi, datetime) as linetime,
        ST_MAKELINE(geom , lag(geom ) OVER (PARTITION BY mmsi ORDER BY mmsi, datetime)) as linegeom
    FROM test_st_12_v1)
UPDATE test_st_12_v1 lt
SET linetime2 = ct.linetime,
    linegeom = ct.linegeom
FROM cte ct
WHERE lt.mmsi = ct.mmsi
    AND lt.datetime= ct.datetime
    AND ct.linetime < interval '6 hour' 
    AND st_length(ct.linegeom) < 30000;
```

To just select the lines, you can do the following. Let's note that having a unique `segmentid` could help joining back the line to the original table

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT mmsi, x1, y1, datetime, 
        datetime - lag(datetime) OVER (PARTITION BY mmsi ORDER BY mmsi, datetime) as linetime,
        ST_MAKELINE(geom , lag(geom ) OVER (PARTITION BY mmsi ORDER BY mmsi, datetime)) as linegeom
    FROM test_st_12_v1)
SELECT *
FROM cte ct
WHERE ct.linetime < interval '6 hour' 
    AND st_length(linegeom) < 30000;
```

Comment: Before to run your query should I have to add a field linegeom in the test_st_12_v1 table point?

Comment: This query updates the source table, so yes. But it is easy to transform it to a `select`

Comment: How coul I transform it? I would simply run this before: ALTER TABLE test_st_12_v1 ADD COLMUN linegeom geometry (MultiLineString, 3035)

Comment: see edit for a `select` version. If you want to add a column, I believe it should rather be of type `geometry(linestring,3035)`

Comment: thank you for the help. I have just to figure out how to edit the existing table, from point to line, avoiding to add and delete geometry columns